# Spark: Print the first ten rows of every year

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have dataset in Spark where there are two columns: the string column (the string consists of the year in the first 4 characters, while the remaining characters are of a word) and the column Integer. Example of dataset row: "2004-dog" 45. I don't know how to print the first ten rows of every year. I arrived at this point:

```
JavaRDD<String> mentions =
            tweets.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(":")).iterator());  


JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts =
            mentions.mapToPair(mention -> new Tuple2<>(mention, 1))
            .reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);
```

Comment: You could use the dataframe api and do it with Window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just an example:

Input Data:

```
+-------+---+
|   year|cnt|
+-------+---+
|2015:04| 50|
|2015:04| 40|
|2015:04| 50|
|2017:04| 55|
|2017:04| 20|
|2017:04| 20|
+-------+---+
```

And, assuming you have some criteria to pick the top 10.
Create a window function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val w = Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy(desc("cnt"))

df.withColumn("year", split('year,":")(0))
  .withColumn("rank", row_number.over(w)) //use rank/dense_rank as you need 
  .filter('rank <= 2) //replace 10 here
  //.drop("rank") //you can drop rank if you want
  .show()
```

Result:

```
+----+---+----+
|year|cnt|rank|
+----+---+----+
|2017| 55|   1|
|2017| 20|   2|
|2015| 50|   1|
|2015| 50|   2|
+----+---+----+
```

Hope this helps!